# Topologically equivalent metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Show that in $\mathbb{R}$ the distance
>
> $d'(x,y)=\left|\frac{x}{1+|x|} - \frac{y}{1+|y|} \right|$ is topologically equivalent to the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}$, $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ But $(\mathbb{R},d')$ is not complete.

Im not being able to show that they are topologically equivalent. I've tried to show that if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open with $d$ then it should be open with $d'$. However, when dealing with the $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$, I don't know how to proceed. Any hint is more than welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that an open ball wrt d is an open ball wrt d' (not necessarily of the same radius), and vice versa. Then, since the open balls form a basis for the topology, the topologies are the same.

Answer (score 4):

One way of playing with this is to note that $d'(x,y) = d(f(x),f(y))$ where $f(t) = t/(1+|t|)$ maps $\mathbb{R}\to (-1,1)$.  In other words, $d'$ is the standard metric on the interval $(-1,1)$ pulled back by the homeomorphism $f$. So this problem boils down to showing that $f$ is continuous and continuously invertible.

Comment: That's a nicely elegant way to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you will do:

First you will show that $d'$ is a finer metric that $d$ on $\mathbb R$.

To do it, first pick a point $x \in \mathbb R$ and let $\varepsilon >0$ be a fixed positive number.

Now, you want to find $\varepsilon'>0$ ( which may depend on $\varepsilon$ and $x$ ) satisfying

$$B_{d'}(x,\varepsilon') \subseteq B_d(x,\varepsilon) \tag{1}$$

So, you will say that for $\varepsilon'= f(\varepsilon,x)$ the relation (1) holds.

Then similarly, you will show that $d$ is a finer metric than $d'$ on $\mathbb R$ and this will complete the proof that these metrics are topologically equivalent.

Comment: But if I show that $d$ and $d'$ are topologically equivalent, as you said, then there is a contradiction in what you are saying or there is a contradiction in the problem, since they ask me to show that $(\mathbb{R},d')$ is actually not complete. (I think that the objective of this exercise is to actually show that completeness is not a topological concept)

Comment: Yes, sorry. You are right. I deleted the edit part.