# Problem 12, chapter 1 of Walter Rudin's Functional Analysis

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

The question is to prove that the metric , defined below, induces usual topology on R :. $d_2(x,y)=|\phi(x)-\phi(y)|$

Where $\phi(x)=\frac{x}{(1+|x|)}$ and $d_1$ is the usual metric.

The continuity of $\phi\times\phi$ and $d_1$ gives that $d_2$ is continuous when $\mathbb{R}$ is given usual metric, but I'm not able to do other way. Any help?

Comment: [Nothing new under the sun](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272986/topologically-equivalent-metric/1273060#1273060) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you observed, one direction follows from continuity of $\phi$. The other direction should therefore follow from continuity of the inverse function.

Observe that $\phi$, viewed as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ onto the open interval $(-1,1)$,  is invertible, and its inverse is given by: $\phi^{-1}(y)=\frac{y}{1-|y|}$. In particular, the inverse function is continuous on $(-1,1)$. As a result, if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converging to some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ in the $d_2$ metric, then
with $y_n=\phi(x_n)$ and $y=\phi(x)$ you have $y_n\to y$, and therefore, by continuity of the inverse, (note that $y_n,y\in (-1,1)$), we get:
$$x_n=\phi^{-1}(y_n)\to\phi^{-1}(y)=x\quad\hbox{as}\quad n\to\infty$$
hence $x_n\to x$ in the $d_1$ metric.